# Get posts from Custom Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I've registered a new post type called `Resources`.

Within the theme root, I've created `archive-resources.php` which looks like this:

```
<?php 

/**
* Template Name: Resources
*/

get_header();

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="resource__wrapper">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query(); 

get_footer(); ?>
```

Within `Resources`, I have a test post called `post 1` (which is published). I would've expected the current `archive-resources.php` to print out `post 1`? But it just prints out "Welcome to WordPress...".

**I've also tried the following:**

**Approach 1:**

```
<?php 

/**
* Template Name: Resources Level 1
*/

get_header();

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $args = array(
          'post_type' => 'resources',
          'posts_per_page' => 10,
          'showposts' => 10,
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'orderby' => 'publish_date',
          'order' => 'DESC'
        );

        $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
        $count = 1;

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

            while ($the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();

                get_template_part('templates/widgets/resource-card');

                $count++;

                if($count > 10) { 
                    $count = 1; 
                }
            }

        }
    endwhile; 

    wp_reset_query(); 

get_footer(); ?>

?>
```

And `resource-card.php` is:

```html
<div id="resource-card" class="col-12 col-sm-6" >

  <div class="resourceCard__wrapper">
    <h3 class="resourceCard__title"></h3><?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></h3>
    <p class="resourceCard__subtitle"> </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Approach 2:**

```
<?php 

/**
* Template Name: Resources Level 1
*/

get_header();


$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'resources',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'orderby' => 'publish_date',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);              

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if($the_query->have_posts()) : 
    while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content();

    endwhile;
endif; 

wp_reset_query();

get_footer(); ?>

?>
```

Where am I going wrong?

**Update**:

Just noticed under `posts` that there's a `Hello World` post (which is why it's appearing on my resources page).

So it seems like it isn't looking for posts in the `Resources` type ...

[image]

**Current Approach:**

***archive-resource.php***

```
<?php 

get_header();

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="resource__wrapper">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>

    <?php
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query(); 

get_footer(); ?>

?>
```

***How I'm registering the taxonomy:***

```
public function post_types_taxonomies() {
    register_post_type(
        'resources',
        build_post_args(
            'resources', 'Resource', 'Resources',
            array(
                'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
                'menu_position' => 20,
                'has_archive'   => true,
                'public'      => true
            )
        )
    );
}
```

In WP Admin, under *Settings > Reading > Posts page is set to Resources*

I have a page called Resources (`/resources`).

... Still not showing post titled `post 1`. I believe `index.php` is taking over since the default "welcome to WordPress ..." blog is still being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your very first block of code is the correct way to do things. *Under no circumstances should an archive template be using a custom `WP_Query` for querying its posts.* WordPress queries the correct posts for you based on the URL, and you output them with the standard WordPress Loop:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

endwhile;
```

There's a few things that could be causing problems though.

Firstly, I noticed though is that your first block of code has the `Template Name` block at the top:

```
/**
* Template Name: Resources
*/
```

This is only supposed to be used so that the template appears as an option under *Template* when editing a page, but that's not how custom post type archives are supposed to work.

That brings me to the next potential issue, which is the post type itself. When you register a post type, its archives will be automatically available at `/resources/`, without creating a page. Creating `archive-resources.php` just tells WordPress to use that template, but if you don't have that template WordPress will still load the correct posts, only it will be using index.php instead. This is outlined in the Template [Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

For this to work though, your post type needs to be public, and `has_archive` cannot be false:

```
// OK
'public' => true,

// NOT OK
'public'      => true,
'has_archive' => false,

// OK
'public'      => true,
'has_archive' => true,

// OK
'public'      => true,
'has_archive' => 'resources',
```

Comment: Hi Jacob, I've had a look at the hierarchy and (even after applying the changes suggested), I believe `index.php` is still being executed over `archive-resources.php`. I've updated my question to showcase how I've registered the taxonomy, seems okay to me, but maybe the issue lies there?

Comment: I just noticed in your question that you have a page called Resources, and this is the Posts page in Settings > Reading. This will replace that page with your blog, and conflict with your post type. You can't also have a page with that name.

Comment: ah, my assumption was that defining it in settings would essentially make it the "index" for that blog. Nevertheless, seems like something has happened. So, I've removed it as the `Posts page` from settings (the `Resources` page still exists), I don't see the "Hello WordPress" post anymore on `/resources` (which is good), but I still don't see my post under Resources taxonomy appearing on the page?

Comment: As I said, you can't also have a Resources page. At least not with that slug.

Comment: Your use of the word "also" suggested only one of them needed removing. So, 1. I've completely removed the `Resources` page from pages. 2. As a result of this, `Posts page` in settings is now `--Select--` (since the Resource page doesn't exist anymore, I can't select it anyway). 3. I would assume `register_post_type` would've defined the resources URL? Because when I now go on `/resources`, it's page not found

Comment: Managed to resolve it :) it was to do with the permalink structures. Thank you for your help :)